# Esxi add existing datastore to another vm

Tags: vmware-esxi, datastore

I hope that someone would be able to help: We currently have a Centos 6.5 VM with a second .vmdk added of 22TB. The OS is located on datastore1 and the second hdd is on datastore2. I have created another VM with Centos7 and want to remove HDD2 from my Centos 6.5 and assign it to Centos7 VM Is there anything that I should be aware of before removing the disk from one VM to assign it to another VM without losing any data.

Thanks, Amo

Answer (score 1):

No

Serverfault requires all answer to be a certain length, so this it just padding, either way no, just get on with it.